# Unjustified downvotes

Tags: discussion

Suppose that I make a question after having searched the existing ones; the question seems to satisfy *all* the conditions usually requested (clear, specific, detailed); but anyway the question receives one or more downvote, even without an evident reason.

Is there something that a user can do against such, unjustified down votes?

Comment: Post a link to your question in question, would you please.

Comment: Yes, having a link to the actual question would help a lot in this case. We could at least speculate as to why you got the downvotes. Sometimes it's obvious to more experienced users, but not every downvoter leaves a helpful comment as they should.

Comment: He says *suppose*. This question can also be answered for hypothetical cases.

Comment: @CamilStaps you hit it on the nail.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Anyway, [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/157937/cmos-dual-of-cascode-circuit) question could be an example: it is perfectly in-topic, essential and clear, but it was downvoted. Maybe because the circuit was initially wrong, and when I corrected it the downvote was canceled? Then, **this** current question has become an example, too. I really don't know why it has been downvoted. Maybe, for a joke?

Comment: That's not a very good example, it has a comment that the circuit appeared incorrect and it's been reversed once it was corrected. You can't tell who downvoted it but it was in that state for almost 24 hours so plenty of time for others to also notice the circuit / comment and the hover for a downvote includes "it is unclear".

Comment: @PeterJ you are right, in my previous comment I was guessing exactly what you have just written. So, let's take this question itself as an example :)

Comment: One thing you should note, @BowPark, is that votes here in meta have a very different meaning: they express whether people agree or disagree with your post. There's a very similar post here in meta [How can we help moderators to control the up-vote or down-vote?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3842/how-can-we-help-moderators-to-control-the-up-vote-or-down-vote), but that recommends stronger actions against silent downvotes. It's got -10 score (+2/-12), but that only means a lot of people do not agree that there should be controls over voting on the site...

Comment: So there's no point in making this meta question an example. I, for one, don't agree with putting any kind of voting control, so -1 from me here. It doesn't mean your question is badly formulated or isn't on-topic here. On the contrary, it's pretty clear, direct and on-topic.

Comment: The voting arrows are inconveniently placed on tablet computers- I've inadvertently downvoted (and possibly upvoted as well) as a result. It's possible to see the downvotes because it shows up in one's own rep but if you don't look at it frequently (or are a person who downvotes frequently) the maximum time to change may have expired already. In one case I asked the victim to perform a minor edit so the blemish could be removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Users can vote how they want. The standards users maintain for voting also differ per user. Some users for example may have the rule of thumb to never downvote questions of new users.

Anyway, have a look at [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121350/205264). From an answer there:

> First, you should never take a down vote personally. Remember that a down vote only takes away 2 points of your reputation, while up votes add considerably more (5 for questions and 10 for answers). Everyone who uses any Stack Exchange site for any length of time will gather down votes here and there. The "best" will take every down vote as an opportunity to rethink a post, and ponder how it could be improved.

And also from that answer, on whether users should explain their downvotes:

> Some users leave a comment on their post asking for the down voter(s) to explain themselves. Be aware that this may not have the effect you want. It may, in fact, just attract more down votes. If anyone responds to your query, it's likely as not to be the person(s) who down voted originally, so your response might not be as accurate as you would like.

Asking for explanation on downvotes is generally not well received though. You're supposed to learn by doing.

I really encourage you to read the whole linked answer.